# how to avoid include the comma right behind a word when copy paste with a mouse

Tags: vim

When copy+paste a text through a mouse right double-click, the comma right behind the text is included. For example. in the text "index,", I hope to only copy "index" when right double-click. Right now, it highlight and copy "index,". What setting in .vimrc should be used to remove the "," in the highight?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: usually, I use `yw` or `yiw` instead of mouse clicking.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The double mouse clicking is more convenient when coding.

Comment: I think most vim users will disagree.

Comment: You should have a look at how text objects work, I guess

Answer (score 1):

This  is controlled  by the  `'iskeyword'` [<sup>?</sup>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'isk')
option. Note that  it does not include a  common by default.
You might want to investigate  what is setting this and make
changes if desired.  You can remove the comma  from the list
with:

```
:set isk-=,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is still there. I checked the iskeyword in a vim session and the list is: iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255. So the comma is not there.

Comment: @William that GUI are you using?

Comment: I use a ubuntu terminal and vim command directly instead of GUI.

Comment: @William this seems to be a terminal configuration then.